# How can I load a HTML template from file during runtime?

Tags: angular, templates, dynamic, components

I'm trying to load a HTML template dynamically to a component in an Angular 8 app. Unfortunately my solution doesn't seem to work in `build --prod` Sop what can I do?

In my project I try to create a dynamic component which loads its HTML template during runtime of the app. So I googled a lot and found this solution below (it is a bit simplified). Its works well in the development env but not for production.

```
import {
    Compiler, Component, Injector, VERSION, Input, ViewChild, NgModule, NgModuleRef,
ViewContainerRef, AfterViewInit, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver
} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Component({
    selector: 'dyn-component',
    template: `<ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>`
})
export class DynComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    @ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamicTemplate;
    @Input() data:any;

constructor(
    private _compiler: Compiler,
    private _injector: Injector,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
) 
{}


ngOnInit() {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let myTemplateUrl = '/assets/scoreboard/BER/template.html';

    const tmpCmp = Component({
        moduleId: module.id, templateUrl: myTemplateUrl
    })
    (
        class {}
    );


    const tmpModule = NgModule({
        imports: [BrowserModule],
        declarations: [tmpCmp]})(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
                  .then((factories) => {
                        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
                        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
                        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
                        cmpRef.instance.data = this.data;

                        this.dynamicTemplate.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
                  });
}
```

So, how can I create a dynamic component where the template URL is given as parameter and this component is created then during runtime? Or: how can I replace a already loaded template from a component?

Please, can anybody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: The reason is that angular AOT precompiles components before. However you can load components dynamically but angular still needs to know about them in entryComponents https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @SGalea that is what I understood while reading the documentation. The problem is that I just have ca. 25 components that using the same data but differ in their HTML. That's why I'm looking for a way to have just one component but the with external loaded template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give you an answer that does not compel you to create 25 components here is a simple way to deal with it. Since you were ready to inject a template dynamically I assume that your component JavaScript will not differ much between components else it defeats the purpose either way.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
<div *ngIf='template == "template1"'>
  <div class="companyLogo">
    <img [src]="logoSourceUrl">
    <label>First Template</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf='template == "template2"'>
  <div class="companyLogo">
    <img [src]="logoSourceUrl">
    <label>Second Template</label>
  </div>
</div>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() template: string;
}
```

Usage:

```
<hello template="template1"></hello>
<hello template="template2"></hello>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f3fm3v) of this.

Comment: meanwhile I wrote something similar :-) But thank you for your help. For me this is a real lack or missing feature in the architecture of angular because often the template comes out of a database. Well, maybe in v9 :-)

Comment: I know what you mean and I agree, but I highly doubt you will see this in Angular any time soon. We lost this feature with Angular 2